# Child actor having more parents

Tags: scala, akka, actor

There is a way how to define a child actor of a particular actor. But how can you achieve that the child actor is child actor of more than one parent actor?
My use case is that there are many columns, each column has several cells. This shall be represented by column actors and cell actors (being children of column actors). In addition, each cell can be parent of a couple of other cells.

Comment: Your requirements sounds odds to me. For what I know about Akka, an Actor should always have only one parent in charge of supervision. I'm not an expert of Akka, but what you're trying to do sounds as an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: Not possible. Why do you want this cell/column relationship to be reflected by the supervision hierarchy? What are you building?

Comment: Columns send messages to cells. Based on the information sent, cell decides whether to send a message with processing information to given segment of other cell. Each cell has its own segment of cell. Thus cell is child of column and at the same time parent of each the cell in the segment. I assumed it goes a bit against supervision pattern but I wanted be sure. Thanks.

Comment: The supervision hierarchy is akka's way of specifying how failures are handled, with the supervisor strategy determining what happens when an actor crashes by throwing an exception. The problem you've described so far doesn't mention failure at all, so it doesn't seem like supervision is what you're after.